# Bootcamps Assistant Says There Is Not Enough Storage Space (39/42) To Partition Drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, bootcamp, partition

Although there is far more than 42 GB available.

I've done my research (not tech-literate) and one solution is deleting time machine drives which apparently factors into Bootcamp Assistant's space calculation.

I recently updated to Big Sur, but have no idea how to get rid of Time Machine Back Up Drives or whether that is the issue at all.

Would appreciate any insight.

[image: Error Message]

[image: Actual Storage Space]

Comment: The amount of available space is the difference between the used space on the total space. This is not the same as the maximum amount of of space the APFS container can be reduced to create the Boot Camp partition. When dealing with a typical Boot Camp installation, the minimum size the APFS container can be shrunk to is given by the command `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits`. You could enter this command in a Terminal application window and post the output to your question. This command will not change your Mac.

Comment: It might also be helpful, if you could post the output from the command `tmutil listlocalsnapshotdates /`. This command will not change your Mac.